# Internal link Shiny infobox to menuItem

Tags: href, menuitem, shinydashboard, infobox

I am creating my first Shiny dashboard! On my 'home' page I added several info boxes. I would like to add a link to these boxes, so that when a user clicks on the infobox, they will be directed to the accompanying menuItem/page from the sidebar. 
So, when someone clicks on the info box stating 'Bevolking', I would like them to be directed to the menuItem 'Bevolking' from the side panel. Although I am able to add a link to an info box via href = "....". I am not able to include an internal link as described above. Could someone help me? See below an image that displays the 'home' page of mij shiny dashboard so far! 
Any help is really appreciated! 
[image: Home page shiny dashboard]